# Spring Websocket getServerName in service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-websocket

I'm implementing routing datasources in my Spring application. One of method to get lookup key is accessing HttpServletRequest and getting current domain as key by invoking method

```
request.getServerName()
```

HttpServletRequest is accessing via RequestContextHolder as below

```
(ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest()
```

or just by autowiring HttpServletRequest

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

Everything is working correctly when I'm in request scope, using standard @RequestMapping annotation in controller. 
I want to do same thing in WebSocket method annotated by @MessageMapping. There is no request scope so Autowiring HttpServletRequest and invoking methot getServerName() gives exception as below

```
No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Message is passed to controller using Stomp and SockJs. Here is my configuration

```
 @Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/sub");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/some");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
}
```

And Controller

```
@Autowired
private SomeService service;

@MessageMapping("/someUrl/{param}")
public void subscribeForMessage(@DestinationVariable Long param) {
    service.doSmth();
}
```

I do not want to pass it from controller to service because invocation chain is much longer and getting current lookup key have to be transparent. 
It is possible to get server name in a way similiar to Autowiring HttpServletRequest? It is possible to inject some "scope" of websocket request or session without passing it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize bean of RequestContextListener to request object other than @Controller ( Request scope).

```
    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }
```